# how to use pentaho kettle to insert double byte(Chinese/Japanese) into MS SQL DB?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, pentaho, kettle, spoon

I put all the data in a spreadsheet, which contains Japanese. In order to save those Japanese characters correctly, I saved the spreadsheet as UNICODE txt. Then I open it, I can see those Japanese display well.

Then I change the .txt extension to .csv(open it still displays Japanese well), and put it into kettle inbox folder.

But after run the kettle, I found the value in db table is ??.

In .ktr file for extracting the value of .csv, the column contains Japanese is defined as string.

In spoon, I already change the .csv file encoding is UTF-16 and format is mixed(dos&unix)

In the stored procedure for inserting the data into db table, the variable holds the Japanese is defined as nvarchar(255).

So I do not know how to solve this issue, please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the solution.

change the input csv file to unicode encoded by using notepad.
change the pentaho content format to MIX and change encoding to UTF-8(16 wont work)